# Hairpin NAT with dynamic WAN IP

Tags: linux, iptables, routing, nat

I have a dynamic WAN IP so if it changes my iptables will no longer apply.

Here is my working hairpin nat, where x.x.x.x is my WAN IP

`br0 - LAN`

`eth1 - WAN`

```
-A PREROUTING -d x.x.x.x -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.9
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/27 -d 192.168.0.0/27 -o br0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/27 -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
```

Is there another way where I don't have to use `-d x.x.x.x` specifically in case my WAN IP changes?

Comment: The enterprise solution to the underlying problem is to contact your ISP and upgrade your connectivity from a residential plan to a (small) business plan with a fixed ip-address (range).

Comment: @HBruijn Could I have this migrated to super user? The question doesn't seem to be welcomed here

Answer (score 3):

Re-write the first rule as:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.9
```

Notice that this would redirect also the connections to port 80 on LAN IP.

If you want to avoid that, with LAN IP `a.b.c.d` change the rule as:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING \! -d a.b.c.d -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.9
```

Comment: This worked for me.  In particular, the first rule worked, but traffic destined for the LAN IP of the router went to the web server instead.  The second rule fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

In the DNAT rule, instead of `-d x.x.x.x`, use `-i eth1 -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL`.

Comment: I deleted the working rule and replaced it with `iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth1 -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.9`... However I'm not able to access my server through public IP anymore. So far the only thing that's working is by typing the IP specifically via `-d x.x.x.x`

Answer (score -1):

```
-A PREROUTING -d $(ifconfig eth1 | grep 'inet addr:' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1}') -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.9
```

or something like that...

Comment: It seams like another answer

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  Your [answer](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) could benefit from more detail. Please edit it to explain how it works and how it addresses the OPs question.